# Does Macros work on a MHT file?

Tags: vba, excel

I have created a drop down menu and button that has a macro but when I save the file as .MHT and then I try to see the content as an Internet page the drop down menu  and the button are not working so I would like to know if these features are only available on the regular excel formats such as xlsm and xlsx

Comment: MHT files are basically HTML. If you want any macro type activity you need to do it in javascript. Note you can open a MHT without Excel installed.

Comment: Does [this site](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/757383-visual-basic-applications-code-webpage-save-mht-file.html) help? How are you saving as .MHT? Or perhaps [this](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Visual_Basic/Q_26240967.html) one?

Comment: Hi Bruce .   What I understand with the first site is that I can add something extra to my vba code so it can work  if I open it as .MHT , is that correct ?

Comment: Hi Nick , I would like the same macro that I have on the excel file but it does not work on the .MHT format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, your suspicion is correct. Macros only work on .xls, .xlsm, .xlsb, and .xlst formats.

Comment: Thanks bro :( I was so happy that the macro was working fine hahaha